# Where to see SQL Server start/stop logs?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, events

I want to know where to see SQL Server start/stop logs for each instances and SQL Server agent/job start/stop logs? I am developing some tools to monitor SQL Server status. I am using SQL Server 2008 Enterprise.

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: did you ask @ serverfault.com ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, the SQL Server error log is stored in the Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL\Log directory. The most current error log file is called ERRORLOG. If you stop and re-start SQL Server, the old log will be archived and a new one will be created. In addition, you can re-cycle the error log by executing the DBCC ERRORLOG command or the sp_cycle_errorlog system procedure.

http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/SQL_Server_Error_Logs

Comment: Thanks! I have found the answer!

Comment: `Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.n\MSSQL\LOG\ERRORLOG and ERRORLOG.n`  based on this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187885(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Unfortunately the link in anwer is broken

Answer (score 6):

There are some undocumented but well know system procedures to read the errorlog from SQL itself:

- **`exec xp_enumerrorlogs 1`** will list SQL Engine errorlog file numbers
- **`exec xp_readerrorlog <errorlognumber>, 1`** will return the content of the requested Engine errorlog file.
- **`exec xp_enumerrorlogs 2`** will list the Agent error log file numbers
- **`exec xp_readerrorlog <errorlognumber>, 2`** will return the content of the requested Agent error log file.

These are the procedures invoked by Management Studio to show the Engine and Agent logs.

Comment: the result is an ordinary result set, one text line per row. You can manipulate it to your wish, including exporting it.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using .NET you can also use the Microsoft.SqlServer namespace to get most of this data programatically. For example, I have used Microsoft.SqlServer.Rmo to get the status of subscribers to a merge replication publication. Depending on what you are using it for, you may be able to avoid accessing (and presumably parsing?) the logs directly.

Check out the [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.agent.aspx) namespace for data specific to the SQL agent.

> **By using the Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Agent namespace, you can do the following**:
>
> - View and modify SQL Server Agent settings.
> - Set up and manage operators.
> - Set up and manage alerts based on system messages or performance
>   conditions.
> - Set up and manage jobs with multiple steps and schedules.
> - Manage proxy accounts for the subsystems on which jobs run.
> - Manage jobs that run on multiple servers.