# detect if sql server errorlog has been recycled

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Using SQL Server 2012.

I want to detect when SQL Server's error log files have been recycled (either by sp_cycle_errorlog having been called, or the SQL server having been restarted).

e.g. I want to detect if the contents of :

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG
```

have been moved to ERRORLOG.1 since the last time a similar check was made. 
This is for auditing purposes.

So far, my approach is :

1) call `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ErrorLogFileName')` to get log file path.

2) get last modified timestamp of ERRORLOG.1 file (from .net code). If file was found and timestamp is later than the last time it was checked, then ERRORLOG was cycled.

Any flaws with this approach ? Any other approaches you can think of ?

**EDIT 1** : the checking will be done from a windows service.

**EDIT 2** : another approach might be to run : xp_readerrorlog, looking for text : 
"SQL Server is starting" and "The error log has been reinitialized". e.g.:

```
exec xp_readerrorlog  0, 1, N'SQL Server is starting', null, null, null, null
exec xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N'The error log has been reinitialized', null, null, null, null
```

This would work, but seems a little slow. (Presumably sql server has to read the whole error log ?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the undocumented:

`exec xp_enumerrorlogs 1`, which  will list SQL Engine errorlog file numbers.

Source: [another SQL Server Error Log question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463809/where-to-see-sql-server-start-stop-logs), answer by Remus Rusanu: